# R remove tags starting with U

Tags: r, regex, string

How do I remove tags like  `<U+0924><U+0930><U+0938><U+0902><U+0917><U+0924>` 
present in sentences.
`Via- <U+0924><U+0930><U+094D><U+0915><U+0938><U+0902><U+0917><U+0924> - Tarksangat ~<U+0938><U+092F><U+094D><U+092F><U+0926> <U+092E><U+0902><U+095B><U+0930> <U+0907><U+092E><U+093E><U+092E>`

I need output: `Via- Tarksangat`

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  Perhaps `gsub("(<[^>]+>){1,}", "", str1)`

Comment: These aren't "tags", they're Unicode characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this might be useful

```
ab <- unlist(strsplit(abc,"[[:punct:]]"))
ab <- gsub("[[:punct:]]|[0-9]","",ab)

ab <- paste0(ab[nchar(ab)>2],collapse="-")
[1] "Via- Tarksangat "
```

## data

```
abc <- "Via- <U+0924><U+0930><U+094D><U+0915><U+0938><U+0902><U+0917><U+0924> - Tarksangat ~<U+0938><U+092F><U+094D><U+092F><U+0926> <U+092E><U+0902><U+095B><U+0930> <U+0907><U+092E><U+093E><U+092E>"
```

Comment: I dont need U0924, i want to eliminate complete tag. i tried these too `sentence <- gsub('[[:punct:]]', "", sentence)
 sentence <- gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', "", sentence)
 sentence <- gsub('\\d+', "", sentence)` but itsn no working

Comment: Output after this update is" `via uuuduuuuu  tarksangat uufudufu ueuubu uueueue`. Please find the input string in the above updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<U.*?>
```

and replace by empty string

[Explnation](https://regex101.com/r/knJ9nT/1)

You can try this:

```
re = /<U.*?>/
str = 'asdfasdf <U+0924><U+0930><U+0938><U+0902><U+0917> tsdfasf <U+0924> 1sadfasdf a2sdf 3sdafasdf <U+0924><U+0930>5<U+0938> 4asdfasdf <U+0902><U+0917><U+0924>'
subst = ''

result = str.gsub(re, subst)

# Print the result of the substitution
puts result
```

Comment: `sentence <- gsub("<U.*?>", "", sentence)` not working

Comment: What language you are trying ? ruby ?

Comment: language is R and i am trying this in R studio

Comment: @Maverick_Mrt Its giving error `Error: could not find function "str.gsub"`. Did u made some import?

Comment: I don't know about Language R, it is a ruby code that i have posted... i think the regex that i have provided is fine... you need to use it with appropriate function in R Language